# Umbraco admin logs out Membership user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, asp.net-membership, umbraco7

Running Umbraco 7.5 with a custom ASP.Net (Web forms) app in Visual Studio 2013 and creating a Membership user via code. This works and creates the user as i can see the user within the Members section in Umbraco.

I can see the user details in debug mode once they have **logged into the front end application** using

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
```

Now, when i log into the admin area i.e. http://example.com/umbraco it then logs out the Membership user so it shows the user (variable from above code) as null.

I can see some web.config entries but not sure what changes i need to make (If any) and im getting the Membership user as per the forum discussions around the internet?

How could i avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options related to logging period, I suggest to try one of them or both.

Set timeout value in the web.config file to 60 mins or whatever you want.

```
<add key="umbracoTimeOutInMinutes" value="20" />
```

Keep user logged in by modifying Umbraco settings file which exists on `Config/umbracoSettings.config`.

```
<keepUserloggedIn>true</keepUserloggedIn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, this was an issue in older versions of V7 and was fixed later on. If you upgrade to a newer version of Umbraco, does the issue persist?